# Change the customer password field Magento

Tags: magento, passwords, account

Can anybody explain how magento customer login works.

In fact, I have a bit weird situation. I need to copy all the customer from existing website to new magento website (I want my customers to use the same username password to login to new website). I know how the passwords have been encrypted in the old website (using normal php encrypt() function with salt) but I can't decrypt them. So I thought of adding a new field in customer account called 'oldpassword' (I followed [this](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6) blog to create new field in customer account). 
What I want now is, when importing the customers, save the old encrypted passwords in 'oldpassword' field. When customer tries to login, it should match the password with oldpassword field using the old encryption method. If password, matches, it should generate the standard magento password and save that in default password field. So next time when customer tries to log in, it should check if default password field is not empty, then just login normally.

**ADDED**

Still waiting for help

I have overwritten the customer->advanceContoller but not quite sure what changes to make in loginPostAction.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to page:   **app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php**

You can see function `public function authenticate($login, $password)`

Also you can see

```
 /**
     * Validate password with salted hash
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        if (!($hash = $this->getPasswordHash())) {
            return false;
        }
        return Mage::helper('core')->validateHash($password, $hash);
    }


    /**
     * Encrypt password
     *
     * @param   string $password
     * @return  string
     */
    public function encryptPassword($password)
    {
        return Mage::helper('core')->encrypt($password);
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt password
     *
     * @param   string $password
     * @return  string
     */
    public function decryptPassword($password)
    {
        return Mage::helper('core')->decrypt($password);
    }
```

Please check this file.

Comment: I have seen these methods but by looking at this you can't tell how to save password in oldpassword field instead of normal password field. On import customers I want all the passwords to go to oldpassword. And when attempt to login, match with oldpassword field.